# Spring 4.3.12 Range bytes не работает

Tags: java, spring, range

Здравствуйте! Отправляю запрос с заголовком

```
Range:bytes=0-99
```

Контроллер должен отдать 100 байт по идее.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/test-blob"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] testBlob(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    response.setContentType("video/mp4");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/path/video.mp4");
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

В ответ получаю весь файл.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:4225991
Content-Type:video/mp4
Expires:0
```

Запускаю все на **jetty-maven-plugin**

Говорят еще в 4.2 появилась поддержка byte-range.
Чтож не так-то?

Comment: А разве вы не должны вытягивать из респонс-запроса кол-во байт и резать файл уже в контроллере?

Comment: @GenCloud Вы имели ввиду наверное из реквеста. Могу сам, но это должен уметь сервер и точно умеет Spring.

Comment: конкретно в Вашем же случаи он ничего просто так ,принимая запрос с атрибутом Range, не будет делать. Вам нужно обязательно описывать логику непосредственно в контроллере